# データベースの内容をブラウザに表示させたい。

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs

グループでウェブページの制作をしています。
検索画面で条件を入れるとそれに該当する結果がブラウザに表示されるようにしたいのですが、データベース（SQL）の設定があまり良く解らず検索内容を入れても表示されません。
バックエンドのターミナルをには`password authentication failed for user "postgres"`と出てます。postgresの現在パスワードの変更までは行えたのですが、それ以降が少しわかりません。
現在のSQLのターミナルは
`postgres=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '自分のパスワード'; ALTER ROLE postgres=#` です。
どなたかアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: まずは問題を切り分けるべきかなと思います。「バックエンドでSQLを実行して結果を取得すること」「ブラウザにその結果を表示すること」はそれぞれ別の課題で今回は前者のことをさしているのですよね？

Comment: また、エラーを見ただけでは、解決が難しいことが多いので回答する側が再現が取れるように作業した内容やどういった環境の設定をしたのかも具体的に書くとよいでしょう。

Comment: keitaro_soさん　お忙しい中ご指摘いただきまして誠にありがとうございます。今回行いたいのは後者にことです。データベースではSQL、Node.jsを使っております。ターミナルでフロント、バックエンドのnpm startは行えたのですが、それでも検索バーに条件を入れても結果が表示されないため、グループ内の仲間に聞いたところ、postgresのパスワードを変えないといけないとのことでした。その時はpsqlは行っておらず、psql -U postgres ->　ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'パスワード';を入れ、ALTER ROLEと出た状態です。また管理ツールにはpgAdminを使っています。画面左のタブにはpostgresのデータベースも表示されています。

Comment: 新しい状況の説明は質問文に追記してください。
パスワードを変えても検索結果は出てこないということですか？またエラーメッセージは変わったりしましたか？